# $f,g\in V^\star$ s.t. $f(\vec{x})=0$ whenever $g(\vec{x})=0$, there is always a $c\in \mathbb F$ s.t. $f(\vec{x})=cg(\vec{x})\;\forall\vec{x}\in V$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I wanted to get some help understanding this question. I'm hoping someone can help expliain it in a way that makes more sense. The question is:

> Let $V^\star$ be the dual space to the finite dimensional vector space $V$ over a field $\mathbb F$.
>
> If $f,g\in V^\star$ are such that $f(\vec{x})=0$ whenever $g(\vec{x})=0$, there is always a scalar $c\in \mathbb F$ such that $f(\vec{x})=cg(\vec{x})$ for all $\vec{x}\in V$

I was given an explanation for this problem by my professor but it kind of confused me, so I tried to show it in a different way, but I'm not sure if what I have works. My professor's explanation was sort of similar to some of the other answers on this site to the same question, in that they used arguments involving the kernels of $f$ and $g$ and stuff. If it's requested, I can write my professor's explanation here too. My attempt at the problem is written below.

Take $\mathcal{B}=\{\vec{b}_1,\vec{b}_2,\ldots,\vec{b}_n\}$ as a basis for $V$. Then $\vec{x}=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\vec{b}_i$ for $x_i\in\mathbb{F}$, so $f(\vec{x})=cg(\vec{x})$ becomes
\begin{align}
f\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \vec{b}_i\right)&=cg\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \vec{b}_i\right)\\
\sum_{i=1}^n x_i f(\vec{b}_i)&=c\sum_{i=1}^n x_i g(\vec{b}_i)\\
\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i f(\vec{b}_i)-cx_i g(\vec{b}_i))&=0\\
\sum_{i=1}^n x_i(f(\vec{b}_i)-cg(\vec{b}_i))&=0 \quad \text{but $\exists\: x_i\in\mathbb{F}$ s.t. $x_i\neq0\;\forall i$}\\
\implies f(\vec{b}_i)-cg(\vec{b}_i)=0 &\implies f(\vec{b}_i)=cg(\vec{b}_i) 
\end{align}
Therefore there is a $c\in\mathbb{F}$ such that $f(\vec{x})=cg(\vec{x})\; \forall\vec{x}$

If anyone could let me know if this is right, or if I'm missing something, or if I should try another method with this proof I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Have you studied inner product spaces? There's a simple geometric picture here if you think of the scalar product $\langle-,-\rangle:V^*\times V\to\mathbb{F}$ given by $\langle f,x\rangle=f(x)$ like an inner product. If $f=0$, the result is trivial. If $f\ne0$, then $g\ne0$ and $f$ and $g$ have the same orthogonal complement, which is a hyperplane in $V$. But that means $f$ and $g$ both lie in the complement of that complement (in $V^*$), which is $1$-dimensional, so they are scalar multiples of each other.

Comment: @blargoner that's a really cool way of thinking about it. One of the times my prof was explaining the problem to our class she did mention hyperplanes and how $f$ and $g$ are both orthogonal to the same hyperplane, but it was more of a side remark and I wasn't sure how to construct an argument using those ideas after the fact. This may be a dumb question but why/how are $f,g$ in a 1d space? I get that in an $n$-dimensional space $V$ the hyperplane is size $n-1$ and so it's orthogonal complement is 1d, but I'm confused as to why functionals $f,g\in V^\star$ are in that 1d space.

Comment: In finite dimensions, $(U^{\perp})^{\perp}=U$ for any subspace $U$ (of $V$ or $V^*$). Here we have $f\in\langle f\rangle=(\langle f\rangle^{\perp})^{\perp}=(\langle g\rangle^{\perp})^{\perp}=\langle g\rangle$.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof shows that if $f$ is a multiple of $g$, then they are both zero at the same points. The problem asks you to show that if $f$ is zero everywhere that $g$ is zero (but not necessarily vice-versa!), then $f$ is a multiple of $g$.

Roughly: you were supposed to prove that A implies B. Instead you showed how to prove that B implies A.

So no, your proof is not right. There's the germ of an idea in there, but I'm not certain offhand that it can be made to say anything useful. And as a general principle, if you can avoid writing things out in a basis in linear algebra, you *should*. (It usually means that your proof will still work in cases where there is no (finite) basis for the space in question, which is often helpful.)